# WPF listBox выделяется красным

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Почему listBox выделяется красным ?

xaml

```
Page x:Class="CompanyApp.View.UserManagementPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CompanyApp.View"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="265" d:DesignWidth="497"
  Title="UserManagementPage">

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listView1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionUsers}" 
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectmodelUsers}" Margin="10,10,100,10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" FontSize="18" Text ="{Binding InfoUser}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="buttonOpen" Content="Подробнее" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="25" Click="buttonOpen_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonEdit" Content="Изменить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="25" Click="buttonEdit_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonDelete" Content="Удалить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="25"/>


    <Button x:Name="buttonOpenUser" Content="Клиенты" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,158,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="25" Click="buttonOpenUser_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonAdd" Content="Добавить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="25" Click="buttonAdd_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonOpenSalesPerson" Content="Продавцы" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,188,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="25" Click="buttonOpenSalesPerson_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonOpenPartner" Content="Партнёры" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,218,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="25" Click="buttonOpenPartner_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Binding

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using CompanyApp.Model;
using CompanyApp.View;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CompanyApp.ViewModel
{
    class ApplicationViewModel
    {
        private String connectionString;

        private AdministrativeModelUsers modelUsers;
        private AdministrativeModelSalesPerson modelSalesPerson;
        private AdministrativeModelPartner modelPartner;
        private AdministrativeModelContract modelContract;
        private AdministrativeModelBoat modelBoat;
        private AdministrativeModelAccessory modelAccessory;
        public ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelUsers> CollectionUsers { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelSalesPerson> CollectionSalesPerson { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelPartner> CollectionPartner { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelContract> CollectionContract { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelBoat> CollectionBoat { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelAccessory> CollectionAccessory { get; set; }

        public AdministrativeModelUsers SelectmodelUsers
        {
            get { return modelUsers; }
            set { modelUsers = value; }
        }

        public AdministrativeModelSalesPerson SelectModelSalesPerson
        {
            get { return modelSalesPerson; }
            set { modelSalesPerson = value; }
        }
        public AdministrativeModelPartner SelectModelPartner
        {
            get { return modelPartner; }
            set { modelPartner = value; }
        }
        public AdministrativeModelContract SelectModelContract
        {
            get { return modelContract; }
            set { modelContract = value; }
        }
        public AdministrativeModelBoat SelectModelBoat
        {
            get { return modelBoat; }
            set { modelBoat = value; }
        }
        public AdministrativeModelAccessory SelectModelAccessory
        {
            get { return modelAccessory; }
            set { modelAccessory = value; }
        }

        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {
            connectionString = AuthenticationWindow.connectionString;

            CollectionUsers = new ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelUsers>();
            CollectionSalesPerson = new ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelSalesPerson>();
            CollectionPartner = new ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelPartner>();
            CollectionContract = new ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelContract>();
            CollectionBoat = new ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelBoat>();
            CollectionAccessory = new ObservableCollection<AdministrativeModelAccessory>();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            //Загрузка клиентов из БД
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT RTRIM(Login) as Login, RTRIM(FirstName) as FirstName, RTRIM(FamilyName) as FamilyName, Customer_ID FROM [Customer]", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        String Login = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Login"]);
                        String FirstName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FirstName"]);
                        String FamilyName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FamilyName"]);
                        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Customer_ID"]);

                        CollectionUsers.Add(new AdministrativeModelUsers { LoginUser = Login, FirstNameUser = FirstName, FamilyNameUser = FamilyName, IdUser = id });
                    }
                }
            }

            //Загрузка менеджеров из БД
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT RTRIM(FirstName) as FirstName, RTRIM(FamilyName) as FamilyName, SalesPerson_ID FROM [SalesPerson]", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        String FirstName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FirstName"]);
                        String FamilyName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FamilyName"]);
                        Int32 Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["SalesPerson_ID"]);

                        CollectionSalesPerson.Add(new AdministrativeModelSalesPerson { FirstName = FirstName, FamilyName = FamilyName, IdPerson = Id });
                    }
                }
            }

            //Загрузка партнёров из БД
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT RTRIM(Name) as Name, RTRIM(Address) as Address, RTRIM(City) as City, Partner_ID FROM [Partner]", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        String Name = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Name"]);
                        String Address = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Address"]);
                        String City = Convert.ToString(dataReader["City"]);
                        Int32 IdPartner = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Partner_ID"]);

                        CollectionPartner.Add(new AdministrativeModelPartner { IDPartner = IdPartner, Name = Name, Address = Address, City = City });
                    }
                }
            }
            //Загрузка заказов из БД
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Contract_ID,Date,DepositPayed,Order_ID,ContractTotalPrice,ContracTotalPrice_inclVAT,ProductionProcess FROM [Contract]", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Int32 contract_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Contract_ID"]);
                        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["Date"]);
                        decimal depositPayed = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["DepositPayed"]);
                        Int32 order_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Order_ID"]);
                        decimal contractTotalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["ContractTotalPrice"]);
                        decimal contracTotalPrice_inclVAT = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["ContracTotalPrice_inclVAT"]);
                        Int32 productionProcess = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["ProductionProcess"]);

                        CollectionContract.Add(new AdministrativeModelContract
                        {
                            ContractID = contract_ID,
                            Date = date,
                            DepositPayed = depositPayed,
                            OrderID = order_ID,
                            ContractTotalPrice = contractTotalPrice,
                            ContracTotalPrice_inclVAT = contracTotalPrice_inclVAT,
                            ProductionProcess = productionProcess
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            //Загрузка лодок из БД
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT boat_ID, RTRIM(Model) as Model, RTRIM(BoatType) as BoatType, " +
                "NumberOfRowers, Mast, RTRIM(Colour) as Colour, RTRIM(Wood) as Wood, BasePrice, VAT" +
                " FROM Boat", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Int32 boat_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["boat_ID"]);
                        String model = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Model"]);
                        String boatType = Convert.ToString(dataReader["BoatType"]);
                        Int32 numberOfRowers = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["NumberOfRowers"]);
                        Boolean mast = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["Mast"]);
                        String colour = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Colour"]);
                        String wood = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Wood"]);
                        decimal basePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["BasePrice"]);
                        Int32 vat = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["VAT"]);

                        CollectionBoat.Add(new AdministrativeModelBoat
                        {
                            Boat_ID = boat_ID,
                            Model = model,
                            BoatType = boatType,
                            NumberOfRowers = numberOfRowers,
                            Mast = mast,
                            Colour = colour,
                            Wood = wood,
                            BasePrice = basePrice,
                            Vat = vat
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
            //Загрузка аксессуаров
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Accessory_ID, RTRIM(AccName) as AccName, " +
                "RTRIM(DescriptionOfAccessory) as Description, Price, VAT, Inventory, " +
                "OrderLevel, OrderBatch, Partner_ID" +
                " FROM [Accessory]", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Int32 accessory_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Accessory_ID"]);
                        String accName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["AccName"]);
                        String descriptionOfAccessory = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Description"]);
                        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["Price"]);
                        Int32 vat = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["VAT"]);
                        Int32 inventory = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Inventory"]);
                        Int32 orderLevel = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["OrderLevel"]);
                        Int32 orderBatch = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["OrderBatch"]);
                        Int32 partner_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Partner_ID"]);

                        CollectionAccessory.Add(new AdministrativeModelAccessory
                        {
                            Accessory_ID = accessory_ID,
                            AccName = accName,
                            DescriptionOfAccessory = descriptionOfAccessory,
                            Price = price,
                            Vat = vat,
                            Inventory = inventory,
                            OrderLevel = orderLevel,
                            OrderBatch = orderBatch,
                            Partner_ID = partner_ID
                        });

                    }
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Обработка

```
    using CompanyApp.ViewModel;
using CompanyApp.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CompanyApp.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UserManagementPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserManagementPage : Page
    {
        public UserManagementPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ApplicationViewModel();
        }

        private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (listView1.SelectedItem is AdministrativeModelUsers)
                {
                    AdministrativeModelUsers name = listView1.SelectedItem as AdministrativeModelUsers;
                    UserInfoWindow window = new UserInfoWindow(name);
                    window.ShowDialog();
                }else if(listView1.SelectedItem is AdministrativeModelSalesPerson)
                {
                    AdministrativeModelSalesPerson name = listView1.SelectedItem as AdministrativeModelSalesPerson;
                    UserInfoWindow window = new UserInfoWindow(name);
                    window.ShowDialog();
                }
                else if (listView1.SelectedItem is AdministrativeModelPartner)
                {
                    AdministrativeModelPartner name = listView1.SelectedItem as AdministrativeModelPartner;
                    UserInfoWindow window = new UserInfoWindow(name);
                    window.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonOpenUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.ItemsSource = new ApplicationViewModel().CollectionUsers;
            listView1.SelectedItem = new ApplicationViewModel().SelectmodelUsers;
        }

        private void buttonOpenSalesPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.ItemsSource = new ApplicationViewModel().CollectionSalesPerson;
            listView1.SelectedItem = new ApplicationViewModel().SelectModelSalesPerson;
        }

        private void buttonOpenPartner_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.ItemsSource = new ApplicationViewModel().CollectionPartner;
            listView1.SelectedItem = new ApplicationViewModel().SelectModelPartner;
        }

        private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (listView1.SelectedItem is AdministrativeModelUsers)
                {
                    AdministrativeModelUsers name = listView1.SelectedItem as AdministrativeModelUsers;
                    EditWindow window = new EditWindow(name);
                    window.ShowDialog();
                }
                else if (listView1.SelectedItem is AdministrativeModelSalesPerson)
                {
                    AdministrativeModelSalesPerson name = listView1.SelectedItem as AdministrativeModelSalesPerson;
                    EditWindow window = new EditWindow(name);
                    window.ShowDialog();
                }
                else if (listView1.SelectedItem is AdministrativeModelPartner)
                {
                    AdministrativeModelPartner name = listView1.SelectedItem as AdministrativeModelPartner;
                    EditWindow window = new EditWindow(name);
                    window.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RegistrationWindow window = new RegistrationWindow();
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: listbox]

[image: xaml]

[image: button Продавцы]

OUTPUT

System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'CompanyApp.Model.AdministrativeModelSalesPerson' from type 'AdministrativeModelSalesPerson' to type 'CompanyApp.Model.AdministrativeModelUsers' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter не может выполнить преобразование из CompanyApp.Model.AdministrativeModelSalesPerson.
   в System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   в System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   в MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'CompanyApp.Model.AdministrativeModelSalesPerson' (type 'AdministrativeModelSalesPerson'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectmodelUsers; DataItem='ApplicationViewModel' (HashCode=45492604); target element is 'ListBox' (Name='listView1'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter не может выполнить преобразование из CompanyApp.Model.AdministrativeModelSalesPerson.
   в MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   в MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   в System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'

Comment: А почему не должен выделяться красным? Смотрите ваши стили, смотрите куда вставляете ваш контрол

Comment: @tym32167, мне нужно, что бы listBox не выделялся. Так как если нажимать на "клиенты" то не выделяется, а как только происходит нажатие на "Продавцы, Партнёры" то выделяется. Код тот же, и я не понимаю почему так происходит.

Comment: Подозреваю что это как-то связано с валидацией, но пока не понятно как

Comment: Я бы сказал, того, что показано в вопросе, драматически не хватает даже для определения проблемы. И вставьте пожалуйста код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Где находится ваш `CollectionUsers` на который вы биндитесь, в `ViewModel` или в CodeBehind'e?

Comment: Добавил код, xaml, обработчик xaml и viewmodel

Comment: Посмотрите исключения в окошке Output, наверняка где-то или валидация не проходит, или тип неправильный.

Comment: @VladD , добавил output в текст вопроса

Comment: Ну вот, вы же сами видите, что происходит.

Comment: @VladD , вижу, но не знаю как исправить(

Comment: @TexnikBy: А когда происходит этот вывод? Это важно. Опишите, что вы делаете. Покамест выглядит так, как будто бы вы присваиваете значение типа `AdministrativeModelSalesPerson` в `listView1.SelectedItem`.

Comment: @VladD , Происходит в 2 случаяx: 1. обработка клика buttonOpenSalesPerson_Click. 2. обработка клика buttonOpenPartner_Click. В случае обработки клика buttonOpenUser_Click, данное действие не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделение убралось после удаления строки:
SelectedItem="{Binding ...}"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так задать стиль по-умолчанию:

```
<ListBox Style="{x:Null}"></ListBox>
```

Comment: не помогло, всё равно выделяется. (Клиенты не выделяются, а Продавцы и Партнёры выделяются)

Comment: Ну это же костыль. У автора где то есть неправильный стиль, а вы предлагает его просто местно занулить.